# CSS binding when array element is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I have a json that returns this:

```
[
    {"home": [
        {"name":"Federico","surname":"","et":"20","citt":"Milano"},
        {"name":"Alberto","surname":"","et":"30","citt":"Milano"},
        {"name":"Mirko","surname":"","et":"30","citt":"Roma"},
        {"name":"Andrea","surname":"","et":"28","citt":"Firenze"}

    ]},
    {"home": [
        {"name":"Brad Pitt"},
        {"name":"Tom Cruise"},
        {"name":"Leonardo DiCaprio"},
        {"name":"Johnny Depp"}

    ]},
    {"home": [
        {"name":"","surname":""},
        {"name":"","surname":""},
        {"name":"","surname":""},
        {"name":"","surname":""}

    ]}

]
```

When there is a valid value provided for name, for example, I would like to change the `background-color` of the input box to white. But if the provided value is invalid, I would like to change the `background-color` back to red.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="context">
    <div data-bind="foreach: personList">
        <button data-bind="text: name,click: $root.getInfoPersona($index()), attr: {'id': 'myprefix_' + $index()}"/>
        <button data-bind="text: $index,enable: false"></button>
    </div>

    <form>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input id="idname" data-bind="value: name, css: { changed: name.isDirty(), notchanged : !name.isDirty() }" />
        <label>Surname: </label>
        <input id="idsurname" data-bind="value: surname, css: { changed: surname.isDirty }" />
        <label>Years: </label>
        <input id="idyears" data-bind="value: years, css: { changed: years.isDirty }" />
        <label>Country: </label>
        <input id="idcountry" data-bind="value: country, css: { changed: country.isDirty }" />
        <button data-bind="click: save">Save Data</button>
        <button data-bind="click: clear">Clear</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ko.subscribable.fn.trackDirtyFlag = function() {
    var original = this();

    this.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
      return this() !== original;
    }, this);

    return this;
  };

  var ViewModel = function() {
    var self=this;
    var pi= (function(){
      var json = null;
      $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'persona.json',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'success': function(data){
          json=data;
        }
      });
      return json;
    })();

    var questionsPerson= pi;
    console.log(questionsPerson);
    self.personList = ko.observableArray(questionsPerson[0].home);
    var n=pi[0].home[0].name;
    var c=pi[0].home[0].surname;
    var e=pi[0].home[0].et;;
    var ci=pi[0].home[0].citt;
    self.name = ko.observable(n).trackDirtyFlag();
    self.surname = ko.observable(c).trackDirtyFlag();
    self.years = ko.observable(e).trackDirtyFlag();
    self.country = ko.observable(ci).trackDirtyFlag();

    self.save = function() {
      alert("Sending changes to server: " + ko.toJSON(self.name));
      alert("Sending changes to server: " + ko.toJSON(this));

    };

    self.clear = function(){
      self.name("");
      self.surname("");
      self.years("");
      self.country("");
    };

    self.getInfoPersona = function(indice){
      var i=indice;
      var ris= pi;
      var n=ris[0].home[indice].name;
      var c=ris[0].home[indice].surname;
      var e=ris[0].home[indice].et;
      var ci=ris[0].home[indice].citt;
      self.name(n);
      self.surname(c);
      self.years(e);
      self.country(ci);
      self.getinfoPersona =     ko.computed( function(){
        return self.name() + " " + self.surname() + " " + self.years() + " " + self.country();
      });

    };
  };
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

[First screenshot: the desired effect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81uJk.png)

[Second screenshot: the wrong effect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybOaO.png)

The effect displayed on the second screenshot happens when I click on the second name to change person. The input box becomes "invalid" with `background-color=red` instead of `background-color=white`.

Comment: It's completely predictable result because you do not reset the dirty flags every time you select another person.

Comment: Can you help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to get it working is to modify your `trackDirtyFlag` extension:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.trackDirtyFlag = function() {
    var original = ko.observable(this()); // make original observable

    this.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
        return this() !== original(); // compare actual and original values
    }, this);

    // this function will reset 'dirty' state by updating original value
    this.resetDirtyFlag = function(){ original(this()); };

    return this;
};
```

...and call `resetDirtyFlag` after you reassigned values for editing:

```
self.name(n);     self.name.resetDirtyFlag();
self.surname(c);  self.surname.resetDirtyFlag();
self.years(e);    self.years.resetDirtyFlag();
self.country(ci); self.country.resetDirtyFlag();
```

Look at [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f867m6q7/) to see how it works.

However in general your approach is pretty far from optimal. Maybe [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html) will be useful for you.